# UDF Reader for CDs on Vista 32

Tags: windows-vista, udf

I'm looking for some software to read some old(> 5 years) CD-RWs I wrote. Unfortunately, they were written in UDF format, and my Windows Vista machine does not accept the UDF reader software written onto the CD.

ISOBuster and CDRoller can read it, but they won't let me suck the data into my machine without paying the registration fee. Since I only have a few CDs to recover, I'm not interested in paying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have read specifically udf support but it's worth it to try [Recovery Toolbox of CD Free](http://www.recoverytoolbox.com/help_cd.html)

Or if you're not affraid to install an outdated driver on your system: [Adaptec UDF Reader Driver](http://download.cnet.com/Adaptec-UDF-Reader-Driver/3640-2100_4-9497911.html)

Comment: I went with the driver. I'll be upgrading the OS soon. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could try [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/).  Its very good at handling most any burnable media.  Although, according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Disk_Format) Windows Vista does support UDF, so I would question the integrity of the disk if it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem: old UDF CD-RW unreadable in windows 7. The right tool appeared to be ISOBuster since it showed all my old data. However I was decided not to pay the registration fee in order to be able to extract data.

Solution was easy:

- Set up a virtual machine with Ubuntu (I used Virtual Box 4.3.28 + Ubuntu 14.04 LTS / 64-bits)
- Insert the old UDF CD-RW in the drive
- Share the cdrom drive with Ubuntu. Cdrom will be mounted automatically
- Finally, CD-RW appears inside Ubuntu and all contents are readable
- At this point you can copy the files to wherever you need